# MySQL database transfer between MAMP and XAMPP

Tags: mysql

I have a database on my MAC on MAMP and I want this database to be used on XAMPP on a different machine. Is it possible to transfer these files between MAMP and XAMPP and can they be properly used on the other machine?

Comment: if you use the phpmyadmin function, and the versions of MYSQL and PHPmyadmin are equivalent, you shouldnt have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

just export database from your MAMP using `Add DROP DATABASE statement` , `Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT / TRIGGER statement` and `Disable foreign key checks` options and import in XAMPP. there is no issue you face. all work fine.